# SQL Selecting all rows except the column with the highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my table(blog) with all the output shown via SELECT *

I'm trying to select all execpt the highest value in the blogid column

I tried using:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog
WHERE blogid < MAX(blogid) 
ORDER BY createddate DESC
```

where I hoped it selects all values that is below the max number in blogid but this gets a error "Invalid use of group function".

any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Does the answer helped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using group by, you will need a subquery to calculate the max value:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog
WHERE blogid <  (select MAX(blogid) 
                 from blog)
ORDER BY createddate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use not in

```
SELECT *
FROM blog
WHERE blogid  not in  ( select MAX(blogid)  from blog)
ORDER BY createddate DESC
```

for selecting max blogid you have to use subquery